# How to add more css properties into an CSS rule without remove other existing properties

Tags: jquery, css

Let say I have some code 
**HTML code:**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <h1>Title 1</h1>
        <p>Text 1</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h1>Title 2</h1>
        <p>Text 2</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS code:**

```
ul li h1 {
    background: #bada55;
}
```

Now, when I hover on `<li>`, I want the text inside  turns to  red. So I write a jQuery code:

```
$('li').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('h1').css('color': 'red');
});
```

The text turns  to red, but it removes the `<h1>` 's background property.
So, anyone show me the solution?
Thanks

Comment: "The text turns to red, but it removes the `<h1>`'s background property" — It really shouldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is CSS rule to hover which works in most modern browsers

```
ul li:hover h1{ color: red; }
```

it will not overwrite original rules

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways. One using only css, one uses jquery aswell.

You could create a class in CSS, containing the red color.Then add that class to the hovered h1.

`h1.redhover { color: #f00 }`

`$(this).addClass('redhover')`

Or add the following in css:

`ul li h1:hover {color: #f00;}`

The first would be specific for some h1, and the other one would be for all h1's that are inisde a ul and a li.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I also tried something similar to your first suggestion. But let say there are many children inside my <li> tag. And when I hover the <li>, each child will change some certain properties. So I have to make a lot of classes and add them to. Is there any way to 'inject' new properties into an existing CSS rule?
The second suggestion is not a solution for my problem: I hover the whole <li>, not the <h1>

Comment: The solution would be that you'd give the classes and allowing them to hover. As @SergeS said, you could add different classes using his way, plus adding the classes. `ul li:hover h1.someClass {#properties#}` etc

Comment: yep, I solved it with @SergeS suggestion. Thanks all of you, I learn a lot from this site :)